Nextjs. Web vitals metrics. TBT
I tried to improve performance of nextjs app and I faced a problem with TBT metric. It's really low ~7sec (use pagespeed insights). What I have done: used lazy images where it's possible, defer all scripts, splitted to chunks, used dynamic import for modals. Maybe I missed smth. But I still have a problem with TBT. I noticed that framework script is evaluated too long look here
I don't understand fully why it's happened. Any ideas about it? And what I can do more in the nextjs application to improve TBT?
Try to improve TBT metric
